# When using JNI to port in existing C++ code, use C or C++ to interface with JAVA?

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface

The existing codes that I'm trying to port in is implemented in C++. After I write my java wrapper and run javah on the class to get a .h header file, .... is there a "correct" way to do things? Should my corresponding wrapper for my existing code be written in C or C++?

Thanks!

Comment: Most popular tools like [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna) or [JNR](https://github.com/jnr) don't support C++, but some others such as [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) and [JavaCPP](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp) do, so the answer would depend on which tool you plan to use.

Comment: I'm actually doing this to develop with Android NDK

Comment: JNI is a C/C++ interface to Java, not the other way around, so your question doesn't make sense, unless we talk about some other tool.

Comment: @SamuelAudet JNI is both a C or C++ interface to Java (Invocation API) and a means via which Java can interface to C or C++. It works in both directions. The question makes perfect sense.

Comment: @EJP Yes, it is a means to interface to C/C++, but it doesn't actually interface with either C or C++. It doesn't matter if we write in C or C++. We could even write our functions in D, AFAIK. But you're right, now that I reread it, the question makes sense.

Comment: @SamuelAudet I have no idea what you mean by 'doesn't actually interface with either C or C++'. That's exactly what it does.

Comment: @EJP Not according Oracle: "JNI ... written in other programming languages, such as C, C++, and assembly." - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/intro.html   JNI has nothing to do with C or C++. The JDK comes with a couple of small extra tools like `javah`, but that's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use plain JNI, you can write in both C and C++. The important thing is that if you are using C++, the JNI functions (like `void Java_com_yourpackage_YourClass_yourMethod(JNIEnv* env, ...)`) must be declared as `extern "C"`, but AFAIK `javah` is doing it automatically.

Comment: javah generates the 'external "C"' block for you. You don't have to worry about it at all, beyond including the header file in your .c or .cpp file. This is therefore not an 'important thing'.

Comment: thanks so much! I'm completely new to developing with the ndk for android, so I'm still a little lost with how everything fits together.